# ASP: Check if remote image file exists

Tags: asp-classic, web, jpeg

I am trying to check if a Remote JPEG File exists.
If yes, then display this else display another one.
Is there any way in ASP to check Files which aren't local?

Comment: Define "remote file" in this case.  How are you accessing the file?  If it's over HTTP then the standard error code to check is 404.

Comment: I have no idea how to access it, thats the question

Comment: OK Nevermind, i got it:

    dim xmlhttp
    dim targeturl
    
    targeturl = 'url    set xmlhttp = server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    xmlhttp.open "HEAD", targeturl, false
    xmlhttp.send
    Response.Write xmlhttp.status
    if(xmlhttp.status = "200") then
    'File exist
    else
    'file doesnt exist
    end if

Comment: Keep in mind that HTTP doesn't really have "files."  A status code of 200 means that the request succeeded.  In most cases this will have the effect you're looking for, but it's not guaranteed.  A server _could_ respond with a 200 status code but still not have the image you're looking for.  (I've even seen someone handle a 404 by sending a redirect (307) to a static "404" HTML page, which was served with a 200.  People break things on HTTP servers pretty often.)

Answer (score 5):

If the aim is only display images then server-side control will be costly / unnecessary.
I suggest you to use the [onerror](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_img_onerror.asp) event. I think the checking image existence on client side is a little bit more effecient way. Although the response status equals to 200, this will trigger even it's not an image file(plain text, html i.e. domain park page etc).

```
<img src="http://strangersite.com/suspicious.jpg" 
onerror="this.src='http://mysite.com/joker.jpg';"/>
```